# Checking for multiple conditions without a break in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a validation script for a Domain Controller. I have an account that has 4 things that I need to verify. The code that I have works but I don't want it to break if one of the conditions aren't met and that is what it is doing now. So, basically I'm needing it to check all 4 criteria, regardless if the condition is met or not.

Here is my code:

```
if(net user "user.dadm") {
    Write-Host "[√] User.dadm was created successfully" -fore GREEN
    if((((uACADA "user.dadm") -band 65536) -ne 0) -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "[√] Password for user.dadm is set to never expire" -fore GREEN
        if((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins").Name -contains "user.dadm") {
            Write-Host "[√] User.dadm was added to Domain Admins" -fore GREEN
            if((((uACADA "user.dadm") -band 1048576) -ne 0) -eq $true) {
                Write-Host "[√] Account Delegation Authority was removed" -fore GREEN
                } else {
                    Write-Host "[X] Account Delegation was not removed" -fore RED
                    }
            } else {
                Write-Host "[X] User.dadm was not added to Domain Admins" -fore RED
                }
        } else {
            Write-Host "[X] Password for user.dadm has been set to expire" -fore RED
            }
    } else {
        Write-Host "[X] User.adam was not created" -fore RED
        }
```

What this does is it will break to the else statement if any of the conditions aren't met but I need it to continue checking each condition.

I know that I could break this up and check each condition individually but I prefer to have it as compressed as possible as it is already going to be over a thousand lines.

I guess the REAL question is if this can be done without making 4 separate IF/ELSE statements.

I'm not sure if its a structuring issue (nested IF) or a command issue (using IF and ELSE when I should use IF and ELSEIF).

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My question is: Why is creating 4 separate if/else statements less compressed than 4 nested if/else statements?  Additionally, my experience is that nested if statements are significantly harder to read, and therefore significantly harder to maintain.

Comment: It is just myself that will be maintaining it.

Comment: You're maintaining it forever?  Even after you leave?  And in the meantime you're sure you'll know exactly what you meant 5 years after you've read the script?  Again, my experience is that reading my own code from more than 2 years ago is not much different than reading someone else's code.

Comment: Well, that's you and you're not me. You're bringing up a moot point and it is off-topic to the question. Don't concern yourself with what I do (or what you assume my capabilities are) and focus on the post, please.

Comment: Bit late to think of it now after my long and literal "no if/else" answer, but have you considered just ... not nesting everything?  `if (test1) { "test 1 passed" } else { "test 1 failed" }` then`if (test2) { "test 2 passed" } else { "test 2 failed" }`?  Might be by far the smallest, simplest change you could do.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I could always break it up into individual conditional statements and it would work exactly how I would need but I want it to be structurally compressed [sic] and grouped together. See the 4th sentence from the bottom in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not tested, but this may be a starting point, though you may just choose the simplicity of multiple if statements.

```
$user = 'user.dadm'

$info = [ordered]@{
    created = "[X] $user was not created"
    neverexp = "[X] Password for $user has been set to expire"
    admin = "[X] $user was not added to Domain Admins"
    delegation = "[X] Account Delegation for $user was not removed"
}

switch ($true) {
    {net user $user} {
        $info.created = "[√] $user was created successfully"
    }

    {((uACADA $user) -band 65536) -ne 0} {
        $info.neverexp = "[√] Password for $user is set to never expire"
    }

    {(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins').Name -contains $user} {
        $info.admin = "[√] $user was added to Domain Admins"
    }

    {((uACADA $user) -band 1048576) -ne 0} {
        $info.delegation = "[√] Account Delegation Authority for $user was removed"
    }

    default {Write-Host 'all are false'}
}

$info.Keys | % {
    if ($info.$_.startswith('[X]')) {
        Write-Host $($info.$_) -ForegroundColor Red
    } else {
        Write-Host $($info.$_) -ForegroundColor Green
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Very nice and beautifully written. Sorry, I just appreciate well-written and unique code. I like the splat idea and I have used that in another script but I didn't think about using it to instantiate [sic] variables and then change the items with a SWITCH/CASE block. I think I may use this, if you don't mind. Thank you for the assistance! You definitely earned the green √.

Comment: I do recommend using the `Write-Warning` cmdlet instead of `Write-Host` with colors though. `Write-Host` would not get written in a way that can be consumed by another script. Example: A test can check if anything was written to the warning pipeline

Comment: @Eris I think you lost me about having something consumed by another script.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write it without `if` tests, e.g.

```
$colors = @('Red', 'Green')
$messages = @('[X] Failed -', '[√] Succeeded -')

$username = "user.adm"

$result = [bool](net user "$username")
Write-Host "$($messages[$result]) Check user account exists" -ForegroundColor $colors[$result]

$result = [bool]((uACADA "$username") -band 65536)
Write-Host "$($messages[$result]) Check password never expires" -ForegroundColor $colors[$result]

$result = [bool]((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins").Name -contains "$username")
Write-Host "$($messages[$result]) Check account is a domain admin" -ForegroundColor $colors[$result]

$result = [bool]((uACADA "$username") -band 1048576)
Write-Host "$($messages[$result]) Check Delegation Authority removed" -ForegroundColor $colors[$result]
```

NB. that if you aren't using `if/else`, you need some other way to do the true/false testing. I'm casting results to `[bool]` and using 2-element arrays. `$array[$false]` casts `$false -> 0` and gets element 0, `$array[$true]` casts `$true -> 1` and gets element 1. That's how the result is turned into the appropriate colors and messages.

Another reasonable way to write this would be to move the Write-Hosts into a function.

```
Function Report-Result { 
    param($Result, $Text)
    if ($Result) {
        Write-Host "Success - $Text" -Fore Green
    } else {
        Write-Host "Failure - $text" -Fore Red
    }
}

$result = [bool](...)
report-result $result "Check password never expires"

... etc.
```

Output looks like:

[image: Screenshot of first example code's output]

Which is okayyyy - it gets your 20 lines of code down to ~10, and has no nesting, and runs all the tests.

---

But it really feels like you're re-inventing PowerShell DSC ("my desired state is that accounts with .adm at the end have their passwords set to never expire") or  [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester) - PowerShell's test framework, ("test that all .adm accounts have passwords set to never expire").

I'm not sure that you can exactly fit Pester into your use case, but it makes me think I would change everything about the script from the way it's structured to the output messages, to make it look and feel like Pester. Particularly I want clear separation of test definitions and printed output, e.g.:

```
1. Here are my tests, with self-explanatory names
2. Here is a loop which runs all tests, and reports on them
```

and that gives me something like:

```
Function Validate-DCUserAccountShouldExist {
    param($Username) [bool](net user "$UserName")
}

Function Validate-DCUserAccountPasswordNeverExpireShouldBeSet {
    param($Username) [bool]((uACADA "$username") -band 65536)
}

Function Validate-DCUserAccountShouldBeADomainAdmin {
    param($Username) [bool]((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Domain Admins").Name -contains "$username")
}

Function Validate-DCUserAccountShouldHaveDelegationAuthorityRemoved {
    param($Username) [bool]((uACADA "$Username") -band 1048576)
}

# Search for all Validation functions and run them
$tests = (gci function: |Where Name -Like 'Validate-DCUserAccount*').Name

foreach ($test in $tests) {
    $result = try {
            & $test "user.adm" 
         } catch { 
            $false 
         }

    if ($result) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "[√] $test - succeeded"
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[X] $test - Failed"
    }
}
```

Which gives an output like:

[image: Screenshot of second example code's output]

My view of my second code is that:

- It's longer
- more complex, less easy to follow
- a lot less duplication of Write-Host
- more structured, separation of test definitions and output
- function names explain what the state *should* be, which makes the output messages work for success/failure
- Output messages are neater in the code, but uglier to read in the output (but could be adjusted, e.g. add spaces when printing them)
- would scale to more tests nicely, just by adding more tests

Comment: Now this is a fantastic answer! I'm not familiar with Pester or DSC but this was very informative. I did like the use of the dual nature of bool values having integer values--that was inventive. The function to write is one that I have used on one of the modules I built not too long ago (it greatly reduces the footprint during integration). I tend to use functions when its repetitious. I was quite lost on the last part, though. I understand what it did but I wasn't following what it meant and how it was like Pester.

Comment: It's not *exactly* like Pester, and it's not a huge change, just changing the focus of the code from your "here is some code with two strings which explain the two results in English" to instead having clearly defined, small, "tests, which pass or fail, with names that make sense for both cases" (and no explanatory strings). I think that's a bit Pester-like, but I could be wrong, I haven't used it for very long myself.